# Randomizing font colors in divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it so that when my page is loaded the font color in my menu divs are changed to a random color from my array. Here is my code:

```js
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];

var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

var textToColour = document.getElementsByClassName("menuItem");

function changeColour() {
  for (let i = 0; i < textToColour.length; i++) {
    textToColour[i].style.color = letterColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * letterColors.length)];
    console.log("Check");
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', changeColour);
```

```html
<div class='menuItem'>
  item1
</div>

<div class='menuItem'>
  item2
</div>

<div class='menuItem'>
  item3
</div>
```

Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: what's the value of `letterColors` ?

Comment: Where is your letterColours function

Comment: So I have deleted all the var red and things and added the colors as strings into a new array and it works.

Comment: Are they rgb values - in which case you would probably need to either use hex or change them to strings - "rgb(0, 100, 63)" etc

Comment: _“Does anyone see where I am going wrong?”_ - how _don’t_ you see that? You are picking a random element out of `letterColors` and try to assign it as the new color. Are those elements valid CSS color values in any way? No of course not, they are _arrays_. Your code is essentially the same, as if you had written `textToColour[i].style.color = [196, 77, 55]` - and that that’s not how this works, should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** : The format of the colors are wrong, look at the following

```js
var red = 'rgb(0, 100, 63)';
var orange = 'rgb(40, 100, 60)';
var green = 'rgb(75, 100, 40)';
var blue = 'rgb(196, 77, 55)';
var purple = 'rgb(280, 50, 60)';

var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

var textToColour = document.getElementsByClassName("menuItem");

function changeColour() {
  for (let i = 0; i < textToColour.length; i++) {
    textToColour[i].style.color = letterColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * letterColors.length)];
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', changeColour);
```

```html
<div class='menuItem'>
  Item 1
</div>

<div class='menuItem'>
  Item 2
</div>

<div class='menuItem'>
  Item 3
</div>
```

---

```js
const textToColour = document.getElementsByClassName('menuItem');

const letterColors = [
  'red',
  'blue',
  'yellow',
  'orange',
];

function changeColour() {
  Array.from(textToColour).forEach((x) => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * letterColors.length);

    x.style.color = letterColors[randomIndex];
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', changeColour);
```

```html
<div class='menuItem'>
  Baguette
</div>

<div class='menuItem'>
  Petit pain
</div>

<div class='menuItem'>
  Croissant
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me to too, thanks. I think I had over complicated with all the var red and green etc. I got those from another bit of code and I thought it would work for this function too.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your random value like htmlcolor format (#123456) but some color codes contain letters. May be you will create random letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**You use rgb colors so use `'rgb('+...+')'`**

```js
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];

var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

    var textToColour = document.getElementsByClassName("menuItem");

function changeColour() {
  for(let i = 0; i < textToColour.length; i++) {
    textToColour[i].style.color = 'rgb('+ letterColors[Math.floor(Math.random() *      letterColors.length)]+')';
    
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', changeColour);
```

```html
<div class='menuItem'>
  try me
</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Just added rgb before the color codes in your existing code snippet. This should work :)

```js
var textToColour = document.getElementsByClassName("menuItem");
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];

var letterColors = ['rgb('+red+')', 'rgb('+orange+')', 'rgb('+green+')', 'rgb('+blue+')', 'rgb('+purple+')'];

function changeColour() {
  for(let i = 0; i < textToColour.length; i++) {
    textToColour[i].style.color =  letterColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * letterColors.length)];
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', changeColour);
```

```html
<div class="menuItem">Item 1</div>
<div class="menuItem">Item 2</div>
<div class="menuItem">Item 3</div>
<div class="menuItem">Item 4</div>
<div class="menuItem">Item 5</div>
<div class="menuItem">Item 6</div>
<div class="menuItem">Item 7</div>
<div class="menuItem">Item 8</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have changed it to and it works fine. I made the mistake of adding variables in for each color. I actually got those from another code snippet that I thought would work for this function.

Here is the Functioning code:

```
var textColors = ["red", "orange", "green", "blue", "purple"];

var textToColour = document.getElementsByClassName("menuItem");

function changeColour() {
 for(let i = 0; i < textToColour.length; i++) {
  textToColour[i].style.color =  textColors[Math.floor(Math.random() *    letterColors.length)];
console.log("Check");
 }
}

window.addEventListener('load', changeColour);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `document.body.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', namefunc());`
waiting for the `DOMContentLoaded` it's the best practice to speed up the page

```js
var arrColor= ['red','blue','green','yellow','purple'];
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

function randColor() {
  for(let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].style.color = arrColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrColor.length)];
  }
}

   document.body.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', randColor());
```

```html
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
```